# What behaviour will f(X) show?

Tags: calculus, functions

Given $f(x)\cdot f'(x)<0$ for all x, then what will be necessarily true for f(x).

1. $f$ is decreasing function
2. $f$ is increasing function
3. $\left|f\right|$ is a decreasing function
4. $\left|f\right|$ is an increasing function

I tried 
As per the given condition either $f(x)<0$ or $f'(x)<0$. Both can not be less than zero simultaneously, $\left|f(x)\right| >0$ in any case (either $f(x)<0$ and $f'(x)>0$ or $f(x)>0$ and $f'(x)<0$. What other information is there in the given condition to find out the behaviour of $f(x)$ out of the given options?

Answer (score 2):

Since $f'(x)$ exists everywhere we can assume $f$ continuous. Notice that we can't have $f(x)=0$ for any $x$, so $f(x)$ is always positive or always negative. Suppose $f(x)>0$ for every $x$, then $f'(x)<0$ and so $f(x)$ is decreasing. Suppose $f(x)<0$, then $f'(x)>0$ and so $f(x)$ is increasing, but in this case $|f(x)|=-f(x)$, so $|f(x)|'=-f'(x)<0$, this means that $|f(x)|$ is decreasing. This is true also for the first case, since $f(x)=|f(x)|$. Hence the answer is $3$.

---

Quicker way: by definition 
$$|f(x)|'=f'(x) \cdot sgn (f(x))<0$$
by hypothesis.

Comment: Thanks I got the point, you are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

Just an example to show that 1, 2, 4 are all false: let $f(x)=\pm e^{-x}$, then $f(x)f'(x)=-e^{-2x}<0$. We can take a sign such that $f$ is increasing or decreasing (so 1 and 2 are not always correct), and $|f|$ is definitely not increasing here. ([mrprottolo](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1615402) has explained why 3 is always correct)

Answer (score 0):

Note that $(f(x)^2)'=2f(x)f'(x)<0$, which means that the square of $f$ and thus also the modulus of $f$ are decreasing. (The square and square root are monotonically increasing on the positive half axis.)

Comment: Does it mean that if $(f(X))^2$ is a decreasing or increasing function then $|f(X)|$ is also decreasing or increasing respectively?

Comment: Yes, exactly that. This is true for any monotonically increasing transformation of function values.